# I am unable to click on a radio button using selenium webdriver as it goes on it clicks the radio button and unclicks it automatically.

Tags: java, selenium, testing, automated-tests, browser-automation

I have seven questions on a web page. each question has 2 to 4 options and i have to select one option for each of the seven questions and then only i can proceed.
I am able to click the option for first question.
But when i am clicking option for second question it clicks initially and it gets unclicked itself. I tried using actions.move to element and when i am running the script i am seeing that webdriver is moving to the element but it is not clicking.

So as i said i have seven questions. when running scrip, the webdriver selects 1st question and when the 2nd question is not selected i manually select 2nd question and then the webdriver automatically selects the other 5 questions.
So, basically the script passes if i manually select the 2nd question.

Is it any property for this question on developers side that needs to be changed OR is it any other error.

```
        Actions act = new Actions(getDriver());

        WebElement que2 = getDriver().findElement(By.id("form:F_15452_1:1"));

        act.moveToElement(que2).click().build().perform();
```

I tried clicking normally for this element. and i also tried waiting  for this element. But i am not successful to click this element.

Comment: Code trials for `tried waiting for this element` and the relevant HTML please.

Comment: @DebanjanB when i put thread. sleep of 2 seconds the script is working fine but not for explicit wait of element to be visible or element to be clickable